# python-chess AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got {move} in {fen}

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to create a chess engine using python-chess, but I keep getting the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dir/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(BOARD.san(whiteMove))
  File "dir\venv\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2824, in san
    return self._algebraic(move)
  File "dir\venv\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2837, in _algebraic
    san = self._algebraic_and_push(move, long=long)
  File "dir\venv\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2842, in _algebraic_and_push
    san = self._algebraic_without_suffix(move, long=long)
  File "dir\venv\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 2878, in _algebraic_without_suffix
    assert piece_type, f"san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got {move} in {self.fen()}"
AssertionError: san() and lan() expect move to be legal or null, but got b2b3 in rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/1P6/P1PPPPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

with "dir" being my project directory.

I have some code to evaluate the best moves:

```
def getMoves(board: Board):
    legalMoves = [move for move in board.legal_moves]
    evals = {}
    for move in legalMoves:
        board.push(move)
        #print(board)
        #print()
        moveEval = evalBoard(board)
        evals.update({move: moveEval})
        board.pop()
        #print(board)
        #print()
    print(board.fen())
    return evals
```

Printing out the board results in the same board as the start of the function, meaning its not fully changed. But the FEN string is the string of the board that would be created if I pushed the UCI move to the board.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I found it. Turns out I was messing up my evals!